# Can i create a security group with the proper permissions and have farm account run only as a service account?

Tags: administration, sharepoint-enterprise, farm-solution

On my SP 2007 environment I been trying to have my administrators not use the farm adm account for their administration and use their own credentials. So we started by creating a security group with local admin rights on the server and determined that some of the functionality also required `dbo_owner` membership towards the content and configuration databases and database server level security (`dbcreator`, `securtityadmin`) roles to run `stsadm` and `psconfig` operations.

My questions now are:

1. Considering I have more than one web application and more than one
   site collection, can I manage my administrators via a security group
   or will I still be required to log in to each site collection and
   set them as site collection administrators? Previously I've had to
   log into each and set each as a site collection administrator which
   only allows to set at a user level (not with a security group).
2. Can a security group be used to manage the maintenance required by
   Farm Admin to the point where I can avoid any user logging in as a
   farm admin and set farm account as service only (prevemto)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, SharePoint groups are not supported for permissions @ webapplication or farm level. You can use AD groups

For the Question 1 : You could create Security Policies @ Web Application Level ,which gives full control to all the site collections under that web application. you can use a AD group as well.

For Question 2 : follow this [Article](http://www.mukalian.com/blog/post/2009/06/26/Creating-NewAdditional-SharePoint-Farm-Administrators.aspx)

Comment: Appreciate your answer.
Yes, the intention is to manage completely through AD.
Answer to #1 worked out. As of #2, we had stepped through a similar process and setup. But to clarify my question, now that #1 has been completed, can I avoid any user logging in as a farm admin and set farm account as service only ? Does my group have equivalent rights to farm admin or is there some functionality that I would still need to log in as farm admin?

Comment: Technically yes, but I am not 100% sure as we use the farm admin to install the SharePoint it might automatically give some other hidden rights too; but for all day to day operations I think it should be good.